# Order of infinitesimal of $\frac{\cos x}{x}$b for $x \to \infty$

Tags: limits, infinitesimals

I can prove that $\frac{\cos x}{x}$ is an infinitesimal for $x \to \infty$ with the squeeze theorem. 
But trying to find the order of infinitesimal, I'm not sure if my reasoning is valid.
Here's what I thought:

We can show that the limit 
$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos x}{x} x^\alpha$$
Is zero for every $\alpha \lt 1$, while it's infinite for $\alpha \gt 1$. 
From considerations about the comparison between infinitesimals, we can easily infere that the order of infinitesimal of the function is thus $\alpha = 1$.

However, I'm aware that the limit with $\alpha = 1$ doesn't exist, so I'm not sure if my proof is applicable.

Could anyone shed light on my doubt?

Comment: $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{\cos(x)}{x} x f(x) = 0$ if $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = 0$, regardless of how slow $f$ goes to zero. (For instance, we could have $f(x)=\frac{1}{\ln(x)}$. Does that answer your question? (It might help to define "order of infinitesimal" here, because this is not a standard term as far as I know.)

Comment: Do you have a precise definition of "order of an infinitesimal", or is it just an informal thing?

Comment: Sorry I thought it was clear: it's just the number $\alpha$